# How change theme of all apps icons using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, icons, themes

Good day. Sorry for my English. I try to create app “theme for desktop” like on screen but not such difficult variant. [Custom icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vAPB.jpg)I know how to set wallpaper using wallpaperManager. But I want to ask how to change style of all icons? I can make custom launcher, get all icons using intent and resolveInfo, show it using recycleView and customize all items. But on screen, it does not look like they used custom launcher. It looks like they only changed theme of system launcher. How can I change style of all icons using kotlin? Do I need to create custom launcher?

I tried to create custom launcher, get all icons using intent and resolveInfo, show it using recycleView and customize all items